# gtags very slow in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24, dot-emacs, gnu-global

I am using gnu global in emacs, everything is ok, but command "gtags-find-tag" search is too slow that cannot bear. only this command is very slow, the others like "gtags-find-rtag" is normal I think.
I delete other config such as cedet, so that exclude these effect, but this issue is still exist. 
Do I miss some config steps of global or emacs? or anyone in other platform(linux) has this issue?

===
my Emacs is emacs for Mac OSX version is 24.3, GNU global is 6.2.8, and my config file is

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d"))
(setq load-path (cons "/Users/xxx/.emacs.d/gtags.el" load-path))
(autoload 'gtags-mode "gtags" "" t)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (gtags-mode t)
   ))
```

Comment: n.b. It's best to not put `~/.emacs.d` itself into the load path -- Emacs writes various files there, occasionally with a `.el` extension, which means it's possible to inadvertently shadow a real library. You should put your elisp files in a subdirectory instead (e.g. `~/.emacs.d/lisp/gtags.el`).

Comment: And `(setq load-path (cons "/Users/xxx/.emacs.d/gtags.el" load-path))` is just wrong. `load-path` is a list of *directories* in which to look for libraries when loading. So you add the parent directory of a library, not the library itself.

Comment: thanks phils, I moved gtags.el to ~/.emacs.d/lisp/, and add this directory to a load-path, but this issue is still exist.

Comment: let me discribe my questions. my GNU global can work, just only this command "gtags-find-tag" search very slowly, it needs about 30s before pop up the tag search result. but the other commands is ok, only this command has this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Global (I do keep meaning to try it), but looking at the [code](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/global/gtags.el?revision=HEAD&root=global), `gtags-find-tag` and `gtags-find-rtag` are very similar functions.

I presume the difference must either be in the completing-read phase, or the find phase, both of which are calling Global.

In the completing-read, 'gtags' passes the option `-c`, while 'grtags' passes `-cr`

In the find phase, 'gtags' passes `-x`, while 'grtags' passes `-xr`.

I would firstly try to establish whether it is faster outside of Emacs than it is inside it. The above might be sufficient for you to test this, but you should be able to figure out the exact commands being used by using `M-x debug-on-entry RET call-process RET` (which you can subsequently cancel with `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry`), and then running the gtags functions and seeing which arguments appear in the stack trace for that function call.

If you can't make heads or tails of the stack trace, try copying and pasting it into your question.

**Edit:**

Based on the information from the comments, it's appears that it's the case-insensitivity argument which is, for some reason, slowing things down to an unreasonable degree.

You should be able to disable that behaviour here:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `gtags-ignore-case` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: phils, thanks for your nice help. I diff the trace of these command enable debug-on-entry, and the difference is that gtags-find-tag will call    gtags-goto-tag("connect_slot" "" nil), but gtags-find-rtag will call   gtags-goto-tag("connect_slot" "r"). ( "connect_slot" is a function name I input to search)
at last, gtag-find-tag will invoke (gtags-goto-tag tagname "" other-win), while gtag-find-rtga will invoke (gtags-goto-tag tagname "r"). the only difference is that the argument pass to gtags-goto-tag .

Comment: Bty, this slow issue only occurs in C++ file, in C file, there is no such problem.

Comment: As I said, `call-process` is the function you're interested in, to figure out the external commands.

Comment: On a different note, version 6.2.9 of Global is available. It could be worth trying that.

Comment: the external command are the same `call-process("global" nil t nil "-pr")`, so I think it is an issue of gtags.el not global.   in `gtags-goto-tag` of gtags.el, I found   `      (setq status (if (equal flag "C")
                      (call-process gtags-global-command nil t nil option "--encode-path=\" \t\"" context tagname)
                      (call-process gtags-global-command nil t nil option "--encode-path=\" \t\"" tagname)))
      (gtags-pop-tramp-environment)
`

Comment: I should probably have clarified that as there are multiple calls to Global, you'll want to use `c` (for continue) in the debugger after noting the arguments for each call, it order to get to the next one. I don't know offhand what the `global -pr` call does, but that's not one of the ones that I was looking at, and there's certainly no chance that the two functions discussed result in the same command.

Comment: Thanks phils, since I am not familiar with emacs. now, I have used `c` to continue the debugger. call process of `gtags-find-tag` is `call-process("global" nil t nil "-pr")` `call-process("global" nil t nil "-xi" "--encode-path=\"  \"" "connect_slot")`; but `gtags-find-rtag` is ` call-process("global" nil t nil "-xir" "--encode-path=\"  \"" "connect_slot")` , the difference is `-xi` and `xir`, I don't know if it is the cause

Comment: I use `global -xi connect_slot` in  terminal , it is also very slow. so it maybe not a emacs issue, it is a global issue.

Comment: while, I also use `global -x connect_slot` its result is the same as the command `global -xi connect_slot`, but it is very faster than `-xi`.

Comment: I had resolved this issue by modify `gtags.el`, disable ignore case in function `gtags-goto-tag`. but your method is much better. Thanks again, phils